# How to whitelist individual email address with rspamd

Tags: whitelist, rspamd

How can a specific from address be whitelisted using rspamd? The address I have in mind is someone@hotmail.com so I certainly don't want to whitelist the whole hotmail.com domain since it is the source for a lot of rubbish. Although the from address can be forged, it's not very likely in this case, so whitelisting on it seems to make sense. If I could figure out how to do it!

Comment: which  OS, and version ? rspamd version ?

Comment: Debian Stretch with latest updates, rspamd 1.9.0-3~stretch

Answer (score 0):

To whitelist email addresses you can use [user settings](https://rspamd.com/doc/configuration/settings.html) or [multimap module](https://rspamd.com/doc/modules/multimap.html).

Comment: That seems a fairly major operation. I had hoped that rspamd might have a standard facility for whitelisting specific from addresses.